# how to add a whole name to an if statement

Tags: c

I would like to know what is the problem with this code.
I want to right a name in the programming and if it's correct give me "Let's go" if it's not give me go back.
I want to add Zay in if statement through right it in scanf. but it gives me an error I searched a lot but there is a problem, pls help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
char name[15];
printf("Type name ");
scanf("%s",&name);
if(name == 'zay')
{
printf("Let's go, %s\n", name);
}
else
{
printf("go back, %s\n", name);
}
return 0;}
```

Comment: 1) `'zay'` is not a string; 2) Strings are not compared with `==`

Comment: `if(name == 'zay')` does not do what you think it does.  `man strcmp`

Comment: `scanf` is hard to use correctly and has many foibles.  At the very least, you should *never* use a raw `%s`.  Since `name` can only hold 15 characters and scanf writes what it reads plus a terminating null, you want to ensure that scanf does not read more than 14 characters.  Use `%14s`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell - as an SO regular just let me say - I frkn hate scanf, tis evil and the cause of much pain to newcomers, and more experienced devs from time to time ,  but we are stuck with it :-(

Comment: @pm100: Well, there is `fgets`.

Comment: @FredLarson yup, I never use scanf, get a line and parse it for me every time , too much hidden logic inside scanf

Comment: @pm100 I suppose it is easier for people teaching C to just teach `scanf` as a all-round input function even though it is exact opposite of its design purposes, instead of `fgets` and then `strtol` or `sscanf`. And then you end up with half of the C related questions being about `scanf`...

Comment: Thank you very much guys. I already started looking for fgets and strtol. you are the best :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong

```
if(name == 'zay')
```

you mean

```
if(strcmp(name, "zap") == 0)
```

see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html

and you need to include `string.h`

Comment: Also `scanf("%s",&name);`. `name` is `char*` so passing `name` sufficies

Comment: @54D ty, I did not notice that